# Is there any easy way to import bookmarks from firefox?

Tags: firefox

The import options had one choice, IE. I was using Firefox and would like to import those.

Comment: Are you using the Tor Browser Bundle?

Answer (score 4):

You need to Export Bookmarks in HTML format (choose this option) from your "standard" Firefox browser.

It produces a file : bookmarks.html (just check where it is placed).

Then, from Tor browser, import the previously created bookmarks.html.

Comment: Just an FYI: This does really solve the entire problem. Many of us have a desire to not only import Firefox bookmarks but to also import FF history, and passwords. But the Tor import menu only lists Internet Explorer as an available browsers to import from. Firefox is not listed but yet it is installed and working fine on my PC.